# List of available WiFi is not working!

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am trying to display the list of all available WiFi but I think my **Network Manager** is not working or not installed at all.
How can I fix this?

This what I get on pressing the WiFi icon:

[image]

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and edit your question to include results.  It appears your network manager is working but you may have an issue with a kernel module or firmware missing for your wireless device

Comment: my problem is a little bit different because i can connect but i can't access to all available wifi.

Comment: @Ahmed202 what wireless card do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the network manager was missing , so this is fixed by :

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```